T-SQL Pivot with Square Brackets
I have a table of key-value pairs that I want to pivot.
Unfortunately, some of the records contain square brackets. How can I transform or adopt my SQL statement to work with square brackets?
Thanks!



ItemID
ItemValue




1
A


2
B


3 [mm]
C




If you execute select quotename('3 [mm]') you can see how the final quoted name should look

Or just use " to delimit the identifier instead of []. So "1", "2", "3 [mm]"

Two ways. You escape a closing square bracket by doubling it up,
select
*
from(values
 ('1'     ,'A')
,('2'     ,'B')
,('3 [mm]','C')
)v(ItemID,ItemValue)
pivot(
max(ItemValue)
for ItemID in ([1],[2],[3 [mm]]])
)p

or don't use square brackets as delimiters but double quotes instead (many hate this).
select
*
from(values
 ('1'     ,'A')
,('2'     ,'B')
,('3 [mm]','C')
)v(ItemID,ItemValue)
pivot(
max(ItemValue)
for ItemID in ("1","2","3 [mm]")
)p

